# Regarding travelling and job joining dates after getting Vignette on Passport - UK Visa - Skilled Worker

Tags: visas, uk, vignettes

I want to understand two things-

1. Till which date can I travel to UK?
2. Till which date can I join my UK job?

Details-
I applied for Skilled worker Visa from India. My Vignette on Passport states start date as 27-Apr-22 and end date as 26-Jul-22. My employer has no problems if I join now or later in June.

On one of the online forums, someone said that *I have to join my job by 24-May-22 (28 days of start date on Visa vignette 27-Apr-22 + 28 days -> 24-May-22)*. He cited the following rule for sponsors-

> S3.9. You must normally stop sponsoring the worker and inform us via your SMS account if the start date is delayed by more than 28 days after whichever is the latest of:
> • the start date recorded on the worker’s CoS (including any amendment to that date you have told us about via SMS while the worker was awaiting a decision on their application)
> **• the date the worker’s entry clearance (visa) becomes valid**
> • the date the worker is granted permission to enter or permission to stay

I asked a UK friend and he suggested that the 2nd bullet point (bold in above quote) means the *actual date of entry (when I reach UK and am allowed the physical entry in UK by the border entry officers)* within the 3 months period starting from 27-Apr-22.

This would mean that I do not need to hurry up to join by 24-May-22. I may travel and join the job next month comfortably instead of rushing now.

Please suggest till what dates can I travel and join the job in UK.

Warm regards,
SG